# ethernet not detecting

Tags: networking, drivers, network-manager, ethernet

Ethernet is not detected in ubuntu14.04. It is detected only after running "sudo ethtool -s eth0 autoneg off speed 100" and after that it works without any problem. It has to be done after every boot. How to fix this?
output of ethtool eth0 is:

```
Settings for eth0:
Supported ports: 
Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                        100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                        1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full 
Supported pause frame use: No
Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
Advertised link modes:  Not reported
Advertised pause frame use: No
Advertised auto-negotiation: No
Speed: 100Mb/s
Duplex: Half
Port: 
PHYAD: 0
Transceiver: ]
Auto-negotiation: off
Cannot get wake-on-lan settings: Operation not permitted
Current message level: 
Link detected: yes
```

output of sudo lshw -C network is:

```
*-network               
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: 
   logical name: eth0
   version: 10
   serial: 
   size: 100Mbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: 
   configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168g-3_0.0.1 04/23/13  latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port= speed=100Mbit/s
```

Comment: Try to install `r8168-dkms` package.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you add the required line to /etc/rc.local:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/rc.local
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit. Add a single line right above exit 0:

```
ethtool -s eth0 autoneg off speed 100
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor. You should be all set.