# Boot time errors about ACPI, unsupported splx structure and a lying master control interrupt

Tags: boot, intel-graphics, acpi, iwlwifi, interrupts

I am getting boot time errors in ubuntu 14.04. After booting it works without any problem. Errors displayed are:

```
 0.669116] dmar: Failed to find handle for ACPI object \ SB.PCI0SD
```

After SD some numbers are also displayed (I could not capture them). This error is displayed in black screen.Next this error is shown:

[image: (see image)]

Also it's written 'Ubuntu 14.04' rather than 'ubuntu'. 
Output of `dmesg |grep iwl` is:

```
[   16.302012] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: loaded firmware version 25.17.12.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[   18.182318] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Unsupported splx structure
[   18.268492] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 3160, REV=0x164
[   18.268837] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   18.269360] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   18.490087] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[   22.183698] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   22.185198] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
```

These all happened suddenly. Changes done today can be seen here https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7vu6OdU_CbuQ1laWHJXSnFRUHc/view?usp=sharing

I am using AMD Radeon R5 M330 graphics card and fglrx driver.
I am new to Ubuntu. Please help.

Comment: I doubt this is a wireless problem. Your image shows errors related to i915 which is a driver for integrated Intel video cards.

Comment: I have edited the question. Please see the changes after which the problems arised.

Comment: @chili555 Please also check this networking question http://askubuntu.com/questions/779730/ethernet-not-detecting

Comment: @SaketJhunjhunwala have you tried installing the package from the comment on the other question?  Many times it works better than the default module